# erazor set variable

Tags: haxe

a little question about erazor https://github.com/ciscoheat/erazor
i know this framwork is based on Razor template engine. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

i noticed the api doesn't fit exactly with Razor (ex: @for(a in p) differs from RAZOR)

this template system for haxe is very handy...
i just don't know how to setup a variable like we do in templo ( :: set mock="tada!":: )

```
//@scope is mycontroller;
@{var mock = scope.getMock()}
@if(mock!=null){
//display some html
}
```

any tips ?
thx

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet works:

```
import erazor.Template;
import neko.Lib;

class Main {
  static function main() {
    var template = new Template("@{var mock = scope.getMock();} @if (mock != null) { @mock }");
    Lib.print(template.execute( { scope : { getMock : function() return "hi" } } ));
    }
}
```

What you missed is that inside a code block all the statements must be correctly closed (missing `;`). Also erazor is loosely based on Razor and uses the Haxe syntax for expressions.